# Resources.getString() method doesn't exist

Tags: java, android

From book I learned:

> For standard strings use Resources.getString(R.string.deal_details)
>   For plurals use Resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.deal_service_
>   new_deal, 1);

But `Resources` class doesn't have this method. Why? Whaat is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use get the resources Object

```
Resources res = context.getResources(); 
res.getString(R.string.deal_details)
```

Comment: ok, thanks. But what is difference between getting string from `Resources` object and getting string via `Activity` `getString()` method?

Comment: There is no difference its just a convenience method that does the same as above code.

Comment: Can I manually create `Context` object? Or I always must to get it from an `Activity`? Thanks

Comment: You cannot create Context object you will get it from Activity/Service. But if you are already inside Activity you can just use even getString

Answer (score 4):

I think you're writing this :

```
String mString = Resources.getString(R.string.mString);
```

Actually, with this syntax you're trying to get the Static method of Resources class, named "getString()". But the getString() is not Static, so you have to use an instance of the Resources class.

Every Activity can give it to you with this syntax :

```
Resources mResources = getResources();
String mString = mResources.getString(R.string.mString);
```

*Note : This code is not optimized and you can remove the first line. I wrote it just to make an example more easy to understand.*